# How to get a distribution using a mean in binary data

Tags: mean, binary-data

So my data isn't truly binary, but actually coded either -1 or 1. It consists of 2500 people (rows) stating their preference for either option1 or option2. -1 means  they prefer option1 and 1 means they prefer option2.
Now I know the mean of the responses, lets say 0.0088 and I want to know how many people answered -1 and how many people answered 1. How do I do this?

Comment: Your data is still binary as there are two options. It doesn't appear that there is a way to get the number of responses for each category once the mean is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean in this case is given by:

$$
\bar{x}=\frac{n_{-1}\cdot(-1) + (n-n_{1})\cdot1}{n}
$$

where $n_{-1}$ is the number of people who answered $-1$ and $n$ is the total sample size. Solving this for $n_{-1}$ yields:

$$
n_{-1} = -\frac{1}{2}n\left(\bar{x} - 1\right)
$$

Once you know how many people answered $-1$, you simply calculate $n - n_{-1}$ to get the number of people who answered $1$.

Here is a quick computational check in `R`:

```
set.seed(142857)    
n <- 1000    
x <- sample(c(-1, 1), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))    
xbar <- mean(x)    
n1 <- -(1/2)*n*(xbar - 1)    
n1 == sum(x == -1)
[1] TRUE
```

For your specific example, we have

$$
n_{-1} = -\frac{1}{2}2500\left(0.0088 - 1\right) = 1239
$$

More generally, whenever $n$ people can choose only two options that are coded as $a$ and $b$, you can recover the number of people who answered $a$ by

$$
n_{a} = \frac{n(\bar{x} - b)}{a-b}
$$